# Unable to ssh from linux to windows

Tags: linux, windows-10, networking, ssh, powershell

Long story short, I have 2 computers at home, one running Kubuntu 20.04 and the other running Windows 10. I can SSH from Windows to Kubuntu no problem, but I cannot SSH the other way around (Linux > Windows).

I have 2 accounts on the Windows machine, both set up as Administrators; the second one has a really simple password (`12345` for testing purposes).

- `ssh -vvv user@ip_adress` outputs:

  ```
  OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.1, OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020
  debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname 192.168.100.16 is address
  debug2: ssh_connect_direct
  debug1: Connecting to 192.168.100.16 [192.168.100.16] port 22.
  debug1: Connection established.
  debug1: identity file /home/traptaku/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
  debug1: identity file /home/traptaku/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
  debug1: identity file /home/traptaku/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
  debug1: identity file /home/traptaku/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
  debug1: identity file /home/traptaku/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
  debug1: identity file /home/traptaku/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
  debug1: identity file /home/traptaku/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk type -1
  debug1: identity file /home/traptaku/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk-cert type -1
  debug1: identity file /home/traptaku/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
  debug1: identity file /home/traptaku/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
  debug1: identity file /home/traptaku/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk type -1
  debug1: identity file /home/traptaku/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk-cert type -1
  debug1: identity file /home/traptaku/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
  debug1: identity file /home/traptaku/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
  debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.1
  debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.7
  debug1: match: OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.7 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
  debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
  debug1: Authenticating to 192.168.100.16:22 as 'traptaku'
  debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/traptaku/.ssh/known_hosts"
  debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/traptaku/.ssh/known_hosts:1
  debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from 192.168.100.16
  debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
  debug3: send packet: type 20
  debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
  debug3: receive packet: type 20
  debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
  debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
  debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,ext-info-c
  debug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
  debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
  debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
  debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
  debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
  debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
  debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
  debug2: languages ctos:
  debug2: languages stoc:
  debug2: first_kex_follows 0
  debug2: reserved 0
  debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
  debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
  debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
  debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
  debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
  debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
  debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
  debug2: compression ctos: none
  debug2: compression stoc: none
  debug2: languages ctos:
  debug2: languages stoc:
  debug2: first_kex_follows 0
  debug2: reserved 0
  debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
  debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
  debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
  debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
  debug3: send packet: type 30
  debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
  debug3: receive packet: type 31
  debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:XSbxZfme7XEpvbDXybRKzMEjC3AVze0f3Dc90clc/2M
  debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/traptaku/.ssh/known_hosts"
  debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/traptaku/.ssh/known_hosts:1
  debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from 192.168.100.16
  debug1: Host '192.168.100.16' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
  debug1: Found key in /home/traptaku/.ssh/known_hosts:1
  debug3: send packet: type 21
  debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
  debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
  debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
  debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
  debug3: receive packet: type 21
  debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
  debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
  debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
  debug1: Will attempt key: /home/traptaku/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:ZNwmYub4bVcSv2BUDA9b3i/lvMON2eIfppnbplBcpAs
  debug1: Will attempt key: /home/traptaku/.ssh/id_dsa
  debug1: Will attempt key: /home/traptaku/.ssh/id_ecdsa
  debug1: Will attempt key: /home/traptaku/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk
  debug1: Will attempt key: /home/traptaku/.ssh/id_ed25519
  debug1: Will attempt key: /home/traptaku/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk
  debug1: Will attempt key: /home/traptaku/.ssh/id_xmss
  debug2: pubkey_prepare: done
  debug3: send packet: type 5
  debug3: receive packet: type 7
  debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
  debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521>
  debug3: receive packet: type 6
  debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
  debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
  debug3: send packet: type 50
  debug3: receive packet: type 51
  debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
  debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
  debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
  debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
  debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
  debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
  debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
  debug1: Offering public key: /home/traptaku/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:ZNwmYub4bVcSv2BUDA9b3i/lvMON2eIfppnbplBcpAs
  debug3: send packet: type 50
  debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
  debug3: receive packet: type 51
  debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
  debug1: Trying private key: /home/traptaku/.ssh/id_dsa
  debug3: no such identity: /home/traptaku/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory
  debug1: Trying private key: /home/traptaku/.ssh/id_ecdsa
  debug3: no such identity: /home/traptaku/.ssh/id_ecdsa: No such file or directory
  debug1: Trying private key: /home/traptaku/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk
  debug3: no such identity: /home/traptaku/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk: No such file or directory
  debug1: Trying private key: /home/traptaku/.ssh/id_ed25519
  debug3: no such identity: /home/traptaku/.ssh/id_ed25519: No such file or directory
  debug1: Trying private key: /home/traptaku/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk
  debug3: no such identity: /home/traptaku/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk: No such file or directory
  debug1: Trying private key: /home/traptaku/.ssh/id_xmss
  debug3: no such identity: /home/traptaku/.ssh/id_xmss: No such file or directory
  debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
  debug3: authmethod_lookup keyboard-interactive
  debug3: remaining preferred: password
  debug3: authmethod_is_enabled keyboard-interactive
  debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
  debug2: userauth_kbdint
  debug3: send packet: type 50
  debug2: we sent a keyboard-interactive packet, wait for reply
  debug3: receive packet: type 51
  debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
  debug3: userauth_kbdint: disable: no info_req_seen
  debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
  debug3: authmethod_lookup password
  debug3: remaining preferred:
  debug3: authmethod_is_enabled password
  debug1: Next authentication method: password
          traptaku@192.168.100.16 password:
  debug3: send packet: type 50
  debug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply
  debug3: receive packet: type 51
  debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
          Permission denied, please try again.
          traptaku@192.168.100.16 password:
  debug3: send packet: type 50
  debug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply
  debug3: receive packet: type 51
  debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
          Permission denied, please try again.
          traptaku@192.168.100.16 password:
  debug3: send packet: type 50
  debug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply
  debug3: receive packet: type 51
  debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
  debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
  debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
          traptaku@192.168.100.16: Permission denied (publickey,password,keyboard-interactive).
  ```
- Linux `sshd_config`:

  ```
  Include                         = /etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/*.conf
  ChallengeResponseAuthentication = no
  UsePAM                          = yes

  X11Forwarding                   = yes
  PrintMotd                       = no

  AcceptEnv                       = LANG LC_*
  Subsystem   sftp                = /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
  ```
- Windows `sshd_config`:

  ```
  AuthorizedKeysFile              = .ssh/authorized_keys

  Subsystem   sftp                = sftp-server.exe
  ```

`ufw` on Linux is disabled, and on Windows I added the proper rules to the firewall, as well as tried disabling the firewall; an interesting and peculiar caveat is that SSH-ing into Windows worked without a hitch when I first set it up on Windows (I did try reinstalling the SSH Service, but no go).

- The problem appeared after I changed the default shell in Windows from `cmd` to `powershell`; I did try modifying the `sshd_config` to allow root login, but nada.
- After I input the correct password 3 times in a row, I get the following message: `Permission denied (publickey,password,keyboard-interactive)`
- As a last resort, next week I will try reinstalling Windows and retaking the steps I took this time until something breaks.

*(Posting this question on AskUbuntu resulted in it getting downvoted)*

Comment: Just an FYI, those `sshd_config`'s really could be more secure ([examples](https://github.com/JW0914/Wikis/tree/master/Scripts%2BConfigs/OpenSSH))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a typo in a Registry edit. SSH-ing into Windows works now.

Comment: What was the typo?

Comment: a "d" instead of an "s"

Comment: it only took me about a week to realize...

Comment: @stefan Just to remember you how can  be easy to mistype something, install `sl` under Linux.